# How to make a Flutter slider go exponential?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use a (Cupertino)slider with which you can pick a number between 1-1000000. For every milestone, I will display another text. (1-10, 10-100, 100-1000, etc.) Since in the beginning, the steps are shorter, I want the slider not being that sensitive, and in the end, I wouldn't care it going with 100 each step, for example. Like it should go exponential. Does anybody have an idea of how to achieve that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried using math.log in onChanged?

Comment: I just found a solution using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider

Comment: But Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use the CupertinoSlider and some class that holds the min and max value, in this example I use RangeValues (it's a flutter class for another type of Slider, but I can use it to save a start and end value). When the onChangedEnd value is equal to the slider value then it displays a snackbar showing the milestone and update the range value from the old one 10 times. division parameter can be used to make a discrete slider, but if the max value is too big you can omit it or pass a null value to make it continuos

```
 class Home extends StatefulWidget {

 @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  RangeValues range = RangeValues(1, 10);
  double slide = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Builder( //Needed to find Scaffold.of(context) and display the snackbar
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return CupertinoSlider(
                value: slide,
                onChanged: (newValue) => setState(() => slide = newValue),
                min: range.start,
                max: range.end,
                divisions: (range.end - range.start).toInt(),
                onChangeEnd: (value) {
                  if (value == range.end) {
                    Scaffold.of(context)
                      ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
                      ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        content: Text('New Milestone reached: ${slide.toInt().toString()}')));
                      setState(() => range = RangeValues(range.start * 10, range.end * 10));
                  }
                },
              );
            }
          ),
          Text(slide.toInt().toString())
        ]
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! this solution is working, but quite laborious. I found a third party slider that is doing what I want. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider. You can use so-called range steps. Unfortunetly I do nor know how to get the current value aóut of it, for example for using it to display it as a text.

Comment: I haven't used that package yet, but reading the example shows that in the onDragging method return the lower and upper values, then it just  pass them to variables created in the stateful widget and setState to save them, then just use pass them to a Text widget and it should be fine